# daemon software to update mysql database in background

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, real-time, daemon

I'm writing a realtime wep application, something similar to auction site. The problem is that I need a daemon script, preferrably php, that runs in background and constantly launches queries to mysql db and basing on some of criterias (time and conditions from resultsets) updates other tables. Performance of the daemon is crucial. Sample use case: we have a deal that is going to expire in 2:37 minutes. Even if nobody is watching/bidding it we need to expire it exactly in 2:37 since the time it started.

Can anybody advise a programming technology/software that performs this kind of task the best?

Thanks in advance

UPDATED: need to perform a query when a deal expires, no matter if it has ever been accessed by a user or not.

Comment: Check this very similar question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734073/mysql-trigger-events-vs-cronjob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to fire queries at time intervals? Can't you just change how your frontend works?

For example, in the "Deals" page, just show only deals that haven't expired - simplified example:

```
SELECT * FROM Deal WHERE NOW() <= DateTimeToExpire
```

Accordingly for the "Orders" page, a deal can become a placed order only if time hasn't expired yet.

Comment: it will need to show to everyone who has it opened that it is expired, so this info is pushed to clients by means of either nodejs or phpdaemon, so the problem is that we need to inform everyone that particular has been expired.

Comment: So, why can't `nodejs` compare current time with `Deal.DateTimeToExpire` and inform a client that is interested in a Deal?

Comment: The changes you want in other tables, are they to handle other actions, like sending email?

Comment: I forgot to mention the real issue, you're right about your option - it will work, but I need to expire it by winning by a system user - that's the problem, sorry, forgot to mention that

Comment: @bytes85: I think you should update your question, adding this info. I suppose you want to make an `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`) on one or more other tables when the time passes (and a deal expires).

Comment: Thanks  ypercube for your link above, that's what I have also figured out, I think we should implement a daemon php script with sleep(const) and all these update procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Does your daemon need to trigger actions instantaneously? If you need a table containing the expired state as a column you could just compute the expire value on the fly or define a view? You could then use a daemon/cron job querying the view every 10 minutes or so if you have to send out emails or do some cleanup work etc.

Comment: thanks, but see above, I missed one important issue, I need to expire it by winning by a system user and everyone who watched it needs to see this