# is there a way to have mysql update records at certain times automatically within phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am not sure how to word this but here is my question:

is there a way to have mysql update records at certain times automatically within phpmyadmin?

Comment: Use the MySQL event scheduler to do the update.

Comment: Your problem can be solve by cron job.
See this link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805742/cronjob-or-mysql-event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805742/cronjob-or-mysql-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mysql Event Scheduler** is very good option, if you want to do all in mysql using sql.

there is a good tutorial on site point for this.
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

if you want to **insert some data or update some data  or delete some data and on other case also** on particular time stamp  on a schedule basis.you can easily use this.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the help everyone! The sitepoint link is especially helpful.

Comment: I have another question, if anyone could answer it.
Using the tuitorial from the sitepoint link that developerCK said, where do I plop this? I tried in the appropriate databases SQL area, but no process becomes set up.

    DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
 EVENT `dude` 
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2013-10-26 04:37:00' 
 DO BEGIN
 
  UPDATE whoa SET blah=1;

 END;

DELIMITER ;

Comment: check that if you have on your event scheduler variable. it is in article.

Answer (score 3):

PHPMyAdmin just client for MySQL. But you could use many solutions of it.

- Use *Unix [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (also known as a “cron job”) or the Windows [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)*

Example for cron

```
0 */2 * * *  mysql -h localhost -u user -ppassword -P 3306 < UPDATE `table` SET `field`='value' WHERE `id`=100500 ;
```

- Use [MySQL scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-overview.html).

Example

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
CREATE EVENT newEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 HOUR
DO
UPDATE `table` SET `field`='value' WHERE `id`=100500 ;
```

Comment: Never heard about the MySQL scheduler... Thanks! :)

Comment: Hmmm... I am clearly doing something wrong, because when I do this one it says there is syntax error: SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1
CREATE EVENT myeventname
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
DO
UPDATE yatta` SET `blah`='1';

I even added the delimeter and end. it executed, but no process is added: DELIMITER $$
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1
CREATE EVENT chibi_shops
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
DO
UPDATE `shops ` SET `shopStockCurrent`='shopStockMax';
 END;

DELIMITER ;

Comment: @micker, add semicolon after first statement.