# Best Practice for a scheduled stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that takes user input from a webform and updates a database.

```
CREATE TABLE AccountTable
(
   RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
   AccountID varchar(2),
   AccountName varchar(50),
   SeqNum int,
   SeqDate datetime
 )

CREATE PROCEDURE [ACCOUNTTABLE_UPDATE]
(
  @SeqNum int,
  @SeqDate datetime,
  @Account_ID varchar(2)
)
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    UPDATE AccountTable
    SET SeqNum = @SeqNum, SeqDate = @SeqDate
    WHERE AccountID = @AccountID
END
```

Each time the user runs the webapp, the table updates the `SeqNum` and `SeqDate` columns. I would like to have the `SeqNum` column reset after ever 24 hours to NULL. Would just putting in the stored procedure checking if the current date is greater than the dates column be ideal or implementing a scheduled task?

Comment: Reset as in turned to NULL?

Comment: Yes to NULL, sorry for the confusion, I'll edit that.

Comment: Why reset data provided by user? Why ask a user to provide data that will be reset?

Comment: @Serg makes great points, and while i'm not sure why you'd reset something a user inputs, based on what you have given i'd just run a nightly process and avoid the redundant date checks. This question will draw opinions though so a moderator or sql badge user may close it FWIW

Comment: The webapp dynamically generates a batch of images in a sequence. The user enters a value determines how many images desired in the batch. We would want that value to reset after 24 hours for a new batch each day.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805742/cronjob-or-mysql-event/14805785#14805785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try running your SP as Sql Agent service's task.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to this I think you should use SQL Agent for scheduling.