# Syntax error when saving MySQL event with INSERT AND DELETE

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I created an EVENT basically does two things:

1. `SELECT` the rows that are more than 30 days old and `INSERT` into the `achieve` table.
2. `DELETE` the rows that are older than 30 days old in the `trends` table.

I separately tested the two scripts and they both work fine but I got a syntax error when put them in the EVENT.

If I only user `INSERT INTO` or `DELETE` script in the event body, it saves fine.

The scripts are:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    EVENT `trend_decayer` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
    STARTS '2016-08-30 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
    COMMENT 'Decay trends that are older than 30 days' 
DO
INSERT INTO `achieve` 
    SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(`trends`.`timestamp`) AS `datetime` 
    FROM `trends`
    WHERE `t`.`timestamp` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS DATETIME)) 
    ORDER BY `datetime` DESC;
DELETE 
    FROM `trends` 
    WHERE `timestamp` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS DATETIME));
```

The error message is :

```
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'INTO `achieve` 
    SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`) AS `datetime` FR' at line 2`
```

Comment: Consider [using crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14805785/256196) instead - IMHO your life will be simpler.

Comment: I will think about that, thanks