# Drop table and copy one table look alike in MYSQL weekly

Tags: mysql, auto-generate

I have a problem where I need to copy a table from MYSQL using this:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```

I need to drop that table weekly and create them again because I dont want to lose the original data. 
Can anyone help me to find a solution where it can be done automatically. I really have no idea about that

Answer (score 0):

What if you have a java program, where you're having the `MySQL` query and let the query be executed automatically through a `cron job` periodically.

Where you can maybe have two separate threads running, or you could do it within the same thread it self. ie, executing the `INSERT` into the newtable and then maybe you can simply drop the old ones.

**OR** you could go with the [MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html). This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805742/cronjob-or-mysql-event) pretty much explains the effective way of going ahead with this as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MySQL EVENT Scheduler`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) for this very purpose like below. You can as well consider using `CREATE TABLE AS(CTAS)` construct instead

```
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
    DO
BEGIN
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newtable;
      CREATE TABLE newtable AS  
         SELECT * FROM oldtable;
END |
delimiter ;
```

Comment: It's a good method, thanks! Will try it. But can I know where to create this event. is it inside the sql in localhost?

Comment: @NorNazirah, it's a SQL statement and thus create it likewise you create any other DB objects like stored procedure or functions.

Comment: i tried to run it in sql but it say that SCHEDULE is unrecognized statement. why?

Comment: @NorNazirah, See edit in answer for a full syntax of creating event in MySQL. Refer the linked MySQL documentation page for more information. Also, which MySQL version you are running on?