# Hi, How to auto execute a php action page on every day at given time, i.e i want to execute a php script at 10:00 am everyday (In windows).?

Tags: php

How to auto execute a php action page on every day at given time, i.e i want to execute a php script at 10:00 am everyday (In windows).? 
I want to take the given time from the database and the n i want to execute the php script at the specified time taken from the DB

Comment: Consider using cronjobs.

Comment: is cronjob possible in windows ?

Comment: scheduled tasks in windows i guess

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use cronjob if you want to execute specific php script, but if you just want to run a mysql 'job', you could use mysql event feature, which allows you to run mysql jobs at scheduled times.

Discussion which one to use: [Cronjob or MySQL event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805742/cronjob-or-mysql-event)

Here's the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html

And here is a simple example: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

On windows 7 you could setup a Task Scheduler task:

- Have Administrator rights
- Start->Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tools->Task Scheduler
- Action->Create Basic Task->Type a name and Click Next
- Finish the wizard as you like

Comment: cronjobs on windows?

Comment: not sure what version of windows we are talking here, but on win 7 you can setup Task Scheduler similar to cron