# How to create a stored procedure and run it on a scheduled time (in MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cron, mysql-event

Need your expertise, I have a script in MySQL and I want it to create a stored procedure and run it on a scheduled time (let's say I need to run it on 7 am and 1 pm).

sample script:

```
update systemuser 
set defaultSiteCode =(select siteCode from site where isremote = 0)
where type in ('U', 'A');
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: how do I create this is Mysql? create a stored procedure?

Comment: [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)?

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't go into technical details about the technology stack and OS you use I will answer your question theoretically.

You have multiple approaches. One of them is ***to set up a cron task***:

1. Create a procedure on MySQL server and save
2. Using any serverside programming language create an executable file with a code that executes the function on MySQL DB. Based on OS you use it might be shell or batch script as well.
3. Set this script as a cronjob

Take a look at the answers to this question: 
[Run a mySQL query as a cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196613/run-a-mysql-query-as-a-cron-job)

---

Another way might be ***to create a MySQL event***. 
Read about MySQL events here: https://t.ly/wmvqv

And here is the comparison of these two options:

[Cronjob or MySQL event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805742/cronjob-or-mysql-event)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the event that I have create and it runs as expected:

--

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `daily_userupdate` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2020-05-01 00:44:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
    update systemuser 
set defaultSiteCode =(select siteCode from site where isremote = 0)
where type in ('U', 'A');

--