# Deleting a row from MySQL after 24 hours in JEE?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee

I am trying to delete a row in my table. Here is my sample code

```
String DBDate = new String();
Long date = new Date().getTime();           
String dateToday = date.toString();             
dbobj.clear();
dbobj.put(LAST_TIME_ANSWERED, "");
int hasDB = dbobj.getFromDB(tableName,column key, primary key);

if(hasDB != 0) {
    DBDate = dbobj.get(LAST_TIME_ANSWERED);
    if(DBDate != dateToday) {
        dbobj.deleteClientDB(tableName, column key, primary key);
    }
}
```

How could I change the date of a timer?
Any help would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you use a TTL on the database row level?

Comment: This is DB dependent, what DB are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql. In my website. I want to clear all datas in my database on a specific user when 24 hours comes

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806127/2051454

Comment: Thanks, will be reading this one. And thanks for all that helped

Answer (score 0):

This is awkward to achieve in java, because you need to run a job on a schedule to achieve this. You should strongly consider using the mysql event scheduler. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806127/2051454) for an example of this.

When you insert the row in the db you should set up an event that is triggered exactly once, 24-hours later, with the necessary sql to delete the row. You would end up with one event per row.

Alternatively, with java and a properly configured server, after each row insert you could add a cron or quartz job that would trigger once, 24-hours later, that would invoke a java function to remove the row. This is harder than using the db's built-in event scheduler.

Depending on your JEE version (>6) you could use an EJB 3.1 timer, as detailed in [this blog post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_16).

Of these options, the db event scheduler is probably the best, because the others can go wrong if the JEE sever is down.

Answer (score 0):

One common practice is to delete database records which are older than some threshold value. For this purpose, the database table should have a column with a timestamp representing insert or update time. When executing the scheduled task there a command is performed (pseudocode, assuming an 'update' timestamp):

DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE LAST_UPDATED < (CURRENT_TIME - THRESHOLD)

Or there is a select query performed to retrieve all these records and handle their deletion one by one including logging and maybe some conditional logic.

To achieve this functionality java SE provides [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which can be used to execute delayed tasks:

```
    // initialize scheduler
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    // schedule repeating task
    ScheduledFuture future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            () -> {
                System.out.println("Excuting task...");
            },
            60,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS
    );
```

The future object can be used to cancel task:

```
future.cancel(true);
scheduler.shutdown();
```

But when using enterprise solutions, there are normally libraries and frameworks, providing functionality for executing scheduled tasks: [quartz scheduler](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz), [spring framework task scheduling](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) or [EJB timer services](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).

Comment: To be clear, you have recommended a job that runs frequently and which clears anything that has gone over the 24-hour threshold. This may be sufficient. However, if you want to delete a record as soon as it reaches 24-hours then you'd have to have a timer per row. Also, this question clearly asks for JEE, so SE and Spring are not in context (though nice to have).

Answer (score -1):

there are two options for this.
1.) use java scheduler  or
2.) use a scheduled job at DB level to clear data at the end of each day

Comment: This is basically what we call a 'one line answer', and they are discouraged on SO. It would be good if you could expand on this a bit. Perhaps give some guidance as to what the options represent and how to choose between them.

Comment: things which could be said in simple, should not be written like essays too :)