# Bash script that executes php file every 5 seconds

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Bash script:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
 sleep 5
done
```

Im trying to call it with cron:

```
* * * * * /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.sh
```

Where is my mistake? Does it matter where the .sh is located?

EDIT:
I fixed all the problems from above. I also created this cron job to prevent multiple proccesses:

```
* * * * * flock -n /tmp/test.lock /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.sh
```

The problem now is that the bash executes the php every 5 seconds and this creates multiple proccesses like:

```
user 12:31 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
user 12:31 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
user 12:31 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
```

How to control this? I need to change the bash script so it can detect if the PHP is being executed.

Is this correct:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
if [ "$(pidof test.php)" ]
then
echo "Running"
else
do
 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php &
 sleep 5
fi
done
```

Comment: Does the script have mode `+x` for the user `cron` would execute it as?

Comment: I dont know anything about this .sh scripts. I just need a php file to be executed every 5 seconds in background.
Im sorry but I dont know what is +x. Im using shared hosting if it makes a difference.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. "Where is my mistake?" means ...? Is the php running or not?  could you test a simpler script to make sure it works, like  `echo > mylogfile.log`

Comment: We only know at least one problem: your script is running one test.php per 5 seconds AT THE FIRST MINUTE, but will be running two test.php per 5 seconds AT THE SECOND MINUTE, 3 at 3rd minutes, ... etc.

Comment: Could you please check my edits in the main question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer is to run you scripts for 12 times only, and put it in crontab

```
#!/bin/bash
for loop in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2; do
  /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php &
  sleep 5
done
```

-- OR --

```
#!/bin/bash
loop=0
while [ $loop -lt 12 ]; do
  /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php &
  sleep 5
  loop=$(($loop+1))
done
```

**--update--**

If your goal is not to have more than one test.php, use this script: (Run it once only, do not putting it in the crontab):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    begin=`date +%s`
    /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
    end=`date +%s`
    if [ $(($end - $begin)) -lt 5 ]; then
        sleep $(($begin + 5 - $end))
    fi
done
```

Explanation: This script calls test.php, and wait for it to terminate (since it dose not have `&` in the end).  Then it measure the time: if it's already passed 5 seconds, it call test.php right away. otherwise, it sleeps for the remaining time so that next test.php will be called at the next 5 seconds starting from the beginning of the previous test.php

Comment: The first one looks dumb, but I perfer it, since it's shorter (even less character counts).  And it runs faster (a little bit).

Comment: Thanks, but the prbolem now is that the PHP script is called too frequently and it creates multiple proccesses like

`user 12:31 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
user 12:31 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
user 12:31 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php`
How to detect if the test.php is being executed at the moment? I need to change the bash.

Comment: That's why my answer is there.  Your original script creates many processes after a few minutes passed starting from when your cron script is installed (see my comment directly under your question).  This script plus your cron script, create exactly one process (test.php) every 5 seconds.  The problem is, how long will your test.php runs?  For example, if your test.php in average finishes in 10 seconds, you can expect 2 processes of test.php are executed simultaneously at any time.

Comment: First, let's define # of processes to fork in your script (in my example above, 12, i.e. `1 2 3 ... 0 1 2`) to be N, and the time to sleep in the script be S,  you can see that in my example, N x S = 60, exactly in 60 seconds, the script runs .php for 12 times evenly (every 5 seconds).    Now, to lower the frequency, you can just lengthen the sleep time S, but keep S x N to be the same, i.e. 60.

Comment: When I open the php through the browser it takes up to 1.5 seconds to execute. I dont know why when the bash calls the php every 5 seconds, it creates multiple proccesses. I have edited my main question, can you check if its gonna work? I need it to sleep if the proccess exist. I found a way not to duplicate the .sh proccesses :) I need a way not to duplicate the .php proccesses.

Comment: If you want only one test.php at any time, that's another story. See my new update in the answer.

Comment: Is that gonna work if test.php takes more than 5 seconds to execute?

Comment: I really need only one test.php at any time

Comment: Yes. even if test.php takes more than 5 seconds to execute. See my updated answer.

Comment: That's great.. I have used the 3rd method. Its working perfectly in my local.I have executed the .sh file via terminal by manually. Its working great. But when i'm closing my terminal the process is not working. So can you please help me to get out of this problem?

Comment: Perhaps using `nohup` command?  example: `nohup myscript.sh &`  It will run in the background, with terminal detached.

Comment: @RobinHsu ahh..Got it.. Thanks for your timely help. Now its working fine even terminal closed.

Answer (score 2):

That cron rule will execute your script every minute. And each script will keep running an infinite loop. So you will end up with many processes..

Unfortunately cron does not allow finer granularity than minutes, so you could leave it the way you have it, but add some locking. Locking that checks if the script isn't already running before firing up a new one.

You could use something like 'flock', if you have it installed,

```
$ flock --version
flock (util-linux 2.20.1)
```

And make your cron so:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * flock -n /tmp/test.lock /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.sh
```

Comment: Which is an elegant solution for an ever annoying problem.

Comment: Im on a shared hosting and it doesnt have Flock, but I will find something like it. I just want to make the script work first :/

Comment: What happens now is that the bash works only when the cron calls it - only once, not like a loop. It executes the php only once. Not once every 10 seconds.

Comment: I called my hosting provider they said we have flock installed. Is this the right cron job:
`flock -n /tmp/test.lock /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.sh`
Maybe every 10 minutes is OK?

Answer (score 2):

Below code I've used linux & cent os servers its working for me

Step 1 => Within this path /usr/bin create autocron.sh file -> `vim autocron.sh`

Step 2 => After creating autocron.sh file -> Put this code within autocron.sh file `while true; do begin=`date +%s`; php executablefile.php; end=`date +%s`; if [ $(($end - $begin)) -lt 5 ]; then  sleep $(($begin + 5 - $end)); fi; done` -> Example excutable PHP file name & .sh file shouble be the same .

Step 3 => After that save that autocron.sh file

Step 4 => Give the permissions for autocron.sh file -> `chmod +x autocron.sh`

Step 5 => And also give the permissions for PHP file -> `chmod +x PHP file location (executablefile.php)`

Step 5 => This command will runs the .sh file in background process even terminal was closed -> `nohup sh autocron.sh&`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `&` character to put the process in the background :

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php &
 sleep 5
done
```

Ensure your script is eXecutable :

```
chmod +x /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
```

but to combine `cron` and this script, there's one way :

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```

because you need only one instance of your script.

If you `cron` doesn't support `@reboot`, another possibility is to add a line in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: I know I might not be able to combine them, but how to execute the script without a cron? The proccess will stop at some point?

Comment: It's an infinite loop, so it's like a daemon, it's running while the computer is on. You can put in crontab : `@reboot /path/to/script.sh` to start the script automagically

Comment: I created a cron with your example. No effect, but maybe the mistake is somewhere in the script or its settings. Not sure how to make it executable.

Comment: You have to figure out if your cron version support @reboot

Answer (score 0):

to make the cron job work (executable) do a

```
$ chmod +x /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.sh
```

to make the bash script call the php

```
$ chmod +x /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
```

finally your php file should have a shebang copy paste this code to top of php file

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

or without shebang you need to change you shell script call

```
php /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php
```

Comment: The cron looks like:
`* * * * * $chmod +x /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.sh`
The bash  looks like:
`#!/bin/bash
while true
do
$ chmod +x /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php &
 sleep 5
done
`
I tested this and i received an email from the cron job:
`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: $: command not found`

Comment: chmod +x is a command you type into your shell, it changes the attribute of a file to executable. this is only possible if you can connect with a ssh or telnet connection. another way to change the executable flag is using a ftp client like filezilla, ftp-connect to your server right click the files and change executable attributes...  "chmod +x" must not be in any of your files as a text

Comment: I only see permissions. It says that everybody can execute it.

Comment: Do you mean that this has to be in my bash script?
`php /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.php`

Comment: ok one problem solved. then change the cron-job to @reboot /path/to/script.sh or use the flock command as described above

Comment: a bash script, started from cron has the #!/bin/bash shebang, while a php script has the #!/usr/bin/php  shebang. if that answers the question. if you have a shebang, you need the file to be executable (chmod +x)

Comment: I just received an email report from the @reboot cron job. It says:
`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: @reboot: command not found`

I have the shebangs in both bash and php file.

Comment: just change the cronjob to * * * * * flock -n /tmp/test.lock /home/user/public_html/website.com/test.sh     forget about @reboot

Comment: I did this but still nothing.
Im worried that even with the normal cron
`/home/user/public_html/website.com/test.sh`
it doesnt execute the script..or the script doesnt call the php I dont know but its not working at all

Comment: Okay, I have 44/50 proccesses now. No good. Not sure if the flock works, but the php was called by the script which is good :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cron doesn't usually have the same PATH variable as your user do.

You should use the full path to the sleep binary '/bin/sleep'. But, as other users noted, your script is going to spawn a copy of the script each minute, which may not be what you're expecting.