# how to set cron job to run an url every 5 second

Tags: shell, cron

I need to fetch an url every 5 seconds. I was reading many articles about it but i didnt find my answer.

As I read I have to write a shell script and inside that shell script I need to write the some command and call that script from a crob job with sleep 5.

unfortunately I don't know how to make that shell script and what I have to write inside it.

I need advise to write that shell script and how to call it from crontab. Below is the crontab I wrote:

```
* * * * * curl http://mysite/key
```

Comment: Please correct your typos and the spelling, then format what you already tried as code, this will make your post an easier read.

Comment: You can try learning about cron from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 0):

Start experimenting with a BASH script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do <here go your commands>; sleep 5; done
```

Then, set a cron job to launch it only once using the `crontab -e` interface.

*WARNING: as mentioned in comments by [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) and [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987273/alexander), you should take BIG care to avoid respawning your process from crontab if using an infinite loop. Study [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58481/can-a-crontab-job-run-concurrently-with-itself) to avoid any pitfalls.*

Comment: The problem if you run this from a cronjob is that every minute one instance of this script will be instantiated and each script will run forever (`while true`...) Ending in a a lot of scripts running simultaniously. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Alexander: If there is *only* one cron-job entry added to `crontab -e` to launch the bash script, I see no chances for the script to be started multiple times (i.e. one time per minute). The only risk is, indeed, if the bash process is not killed manually by the next day, the cronjob will spawn another instance of it (if the cron schedule is set to 1 run per day).

Comment: You cannot assume the next cronjob will kill the previous one. There are many questions here and in [sf] covering the issue, which in general can be done with some kind of lock files. But the current solution is not reliable in this sense. See [Can a crontab job run concurrently with itself?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58481/40596)

Comment: For starting script you can use nohup. This allows you to close console without killing your script. Still if you need you script running all the time you need other daemon to restart your script if it fail or if someone kill it. For that purpose you can use systemd or demonize tool, depends on what distribution you use.

Comment: @fedorqui: thanks for comments. Indeed, OP should take BIG care to avoid respawning the process multiple times if launching a script containing an inifinite loop. I will post your link in the answer, with your permission.

Answer (score 0):

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983894/bash-script-that-executes-php-file-every-5-seconds).

You can run a cron job every minute and then have that script execute (approximately) for a minute, e.g.,

```
for i in $(seq 11); do curl http://mysite/key; sleep 5; done
```

(This is `bash`.) I used 11 iterations in this case.

Or, this time-based solution:

```
t=$(date +"%s"); t=$(($t+60)); while [[ $(date +"%s") -lt $t ]]; do curl http://mysite/key; sleep 5; done
```